# Intstalling ibm_db package for node.js using github

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I am using node version 4.1.1. I am trying to install ibm_db package for Node.js using: `npm install git+https://git@github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db.git#v4_support`. It turns out my company does not allow name resolution from terminal and so it fails with error: `error: Couldn't resolve host 'github.com' while accessing https://git@github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db.git/info/refs`. Is there any work-around?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on 64bit Windows platform, you can install ibm_db for v4.x using "npm install ibm_db" command now. The latest release of ibm_db support it on Windows. But, for non-windows platforms, you still need to install from git-hub. Thanks.